# sklearn K-means returning null values for some observation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am running sklearn k-means on my dataset. MY result file returns clusters only for some of my data. Other parts of my data, there is no cluster value. Its null. 
Any ideas why that is happening and how I can avoid that?

Comment: really hard to answer that without seeing any code or the results file. Are you sure the entire data set is being used in the algorithm? How are you then applying the cluster labels to the data?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]